# SwiftUI TabView different behavior on simulator and device

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm developing a SwiftUI application and have encountered an issue with TabView where the tab items display differently on an iOS device compared to the iOS simulator.

**Code:**

```
struct TabViewTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("First", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
                SecondView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Second", systemImage: "chart.pie")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a clean project with the above code to isolate the issue. The tab bar appears with the expected styling in the simulator but on the actual device, the selected tab item has an unwanted background color.

**Expected Behavior:**

The selected tab item should only change the tint color of the label without any additional background color, as it appears in the simulator.

**Actual Behavior:**

On my iPhone 15 running iOS 17.2.1, the selected tab item has an additional background color that I did not set and do not want. See the difference in the screenshots below for simulator vs iOS device.

**Question:**

How can I remove the unexpected background color for the selected tab item on the device, so it matches the appearance in the simulator?

**Environment:**

Xcode 15.1
iOS Simulator running iOS 17.2
Actual device: iPhone 15 running iOS 17.2.1

[image: Device]
[image: Simulator]

Comment: Do you have button shapes enabled in your device's accessibility settings?

Comment: @vollkorntomate Thanks for suggestion but no. The button shapes are disabled on my device.
But tested on wife's iPhone 11 Pro Max and everything is ok so will have to keep digging to see what Settings on my device are different.

Comment: On the physical device you might also want to check whether app-specific accessibility settings have been set (Accessibility > Per-App Settings).

Comment: The problem was with the Accessibility issues. Previously I had enabled Grayscale which adds such shapes. And then if you just disable Color filters without changing to something like Red/Greed filters it will still show the shapes.